# Why does classOf[A.type] not compile?

Tags: scala, singleton-type

The signature of [`Predef.classOf`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/bda011524f7619b61b4fcc8172f088d2445e947e/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L122) is

```
def classOf[T]: Class[T]
```

so emulating the above signature with

```
object Foo
def f[T]: Class[T] = null
```

why the following compiles

```
f[Foo.type]         // ok
```

but the following errors in Scala

```
classOf[Foo.type]   // error: class type required but Foo.type found
```

---

EDIT: In Scala 2.13.4 and onwards the above does works (as pointed out in the comments), however similar compile-time error still happens in the following scenario

```
val foo: Foo.type = Foo

f[foo.type]         // ok              
classOf[foo.type]   // error: class type required but foo.type found
```

Comment: You can only get a classtag of something that is a class, `Foo.type` is not a class. - Note that here we are talking about what the compiler understand with classes, of course in the JVM am object has an underlying class at runtime, but for the language spec an object is not a class.

Comment: Actually it does compile in 2.13.4 and onwards.

Comment: So <2.13.4 `Foo.type` is considered not to have a class, but >=2.13.4 it is considered to have a class?

Comment: Even before 2.13.4 you could still do `Foo.getClass`. You can read about the change with `classOf` [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/9279) and in the linked tickets.

Comment: [There are more types than classes](https://github.com/typelevel/typelevel.github.com/blob/6e5f1612fc63714efa817298540e11caa4796dcb/posts/2017-02-13-more-types-than-classes.md) states: _"`greeting.type` ... has no class with the same name."_ What did they mean by that?

Comment: In that text `greeting` is just a `val` pointing to a `String` so at runtime there is no class that represents that specific type. A Scala `object` is a bit of a special case because `object Foo` does generate a new class called `Foo$`, of which `Foo` is the only instance.

Comment: @Jasper-M but it is correct to say the `object Foo` generates a class `Foo$` in the language level? I sometimes got the impression that the stdlib assumes too much that it will be running in the JVM.

Comment: @Luis I think that it's more an implementation detail indeed. But apparently there are some use cases that require `classOf[Foo.type]` to work (i.e. annotations that require literals as input). I think it _is_ part of the language though that `object Foo` defines a new class that has exactly 1 instance. But what that class is and how it works is an implementation detail.